# How do I reach the Dahl chest behind the electric fence in the area Pity's Fall?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

There's a Dahl chest in Pity's Fall, behind some electric fences. It's in the bottom floor of a large room with multiple levels, where you fight a lot of enemies.

The mission objective at this point is "Get to the engine room".

It looks like it only requires a single switch because there's just one red light above the door.

Comment: It would help if you added a screenshot of the map and your view of the chest.

Comment: Batophobia, those are different chests in different locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stand at the entrance to Pity's Fall and look up you will see a Red cable. It leads up to one of the catwalks west. Most players will jump up onto it for a slam switch.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll check it out later. I recall a yellow cable and I definitely looked for a red cable but couldn't find one. I'll try again then.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I saw it was way high up, so I had to jump on some railings, and then float from there to the catwalk.

Answer (score 1):

Stay in the large hall and simply get higher, until you find the pressure plate on a catwalk:

Simply follow the path as if you were completing the main quest mission but instead of exiting the hall, keep going left.

[image: map with path]

Jump on the railings and then on the wall plates until you can jump to the catwalk from there. Then double-jump and slam the pressure plate. You can drop down to get back to the crate room.

If you find yourself following a red cable outside of this hall (in the direction towards level entrance), it will lead to what seems to be a fuse box which you can shoot or slam but that's not related to this Dahl Crate.